# Не меняется фон сайта

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте
Сайт http://193land.com/

Хочу изменить фон с белого на серый.

Делаю это через админку, поставил серый цвет, но в итоге фон дальше белый.

В чем может быть проблема и как решить это? Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в style.css

```
.site {
    background: #a5a5a5;
}
```